# How to pre select value with "Select2"

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I have read some post, but i can't get this to work! I'm trying to pre-select "2015" in "Select2", but nothing is selected!

As, a bonus i'd like help with switching the static dates, to "thisYear" and "pastYear". How should that JS look like together?

**HTML**

```
<!-- Select2 choose_year -->
<div>
  <input type='hidden' class='col-md-2' id='choose_year' name='choose_year'>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#choose_year").select2({
    data:[
      {id:0,text:'2015'},
      {id:1,text:'2014'}
    ],
    val: ["0"]
  });
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the val() method

```
$("#choose_year").select2({
    data: [{
        id: 0,
        text: '2015'
    }, {
        id: 1,
        text: '2014'
    }],
    val: ["0"]
}).select2('val', 1);
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/fxkLamjv/)

Comment: Thank you. Works very well!

Comment: No solution for my bonus question? :D